# how to get notified by back-button pressed without override OS methods?

Tags: android

I am asking how can my activity get notified that the back button has been pressed.
I know that I can override onBackPressed or onKeyEvenet accroding to [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html) blog post

but i think this is not optimized way to do so, since I have to restart the previous activity my-self while the OS is already doing this for me.
I just need to be notified that back button is pressed to set a flag to be true where I can use this flag later to know if the hardware back button has been pressed or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but i think this is not optimized way to do so, since I have to restart the previous activity my-self

This is the best way to override the back button I know of, however that blog doesn't explicitly say you can call the super method... Have you tried this?

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Set your flag here

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer Sam but can u tell me how can I pass the value of this flag that I have set (in Activity A) to the backward Activity (N-1)?

Comment: If you want to return data from a child Activity to it's parent you should use `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()` in the parent Activity and [`setResult(Int, Intent)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29) in the child Activity.

Comment: here is the problem exactly, I dont start the activity myself but in fact, I let OS to start it by calling super.onBackPressed() as you suggested in your answer, so I am asking if there is any other way to send the value of this flag to previous activity?

Comment: "I let OS to start it by calling super.onBackPressed()" The `onBackPressed()` method does not _start_ an Activity, it _finishes_ the current, child Activity allowing the parent Activity to _resume_. If you want to pass information from "Activity A" back to "Activity (N-1)" you need to use `setResult()` in "Activity A" and `onActivityResult()` in "Activity (N-1)".